# How to detect whether current wifi network has proxy settings?

Tags: android, networking, proxy

I'm developing an android app which deals with network connection. If my device is connected to a normal WiFi network then it works properly, but if I connect my device to a WiFi network having proxy settings then my app does not work. Those network calls doesn't work if WiFi has proxy settings.

Is there any solution for detecting whether WiFi network has proxy settings?

Comment: It's not the Wi-Fi that would have proxy settings, it's the network on which the Wi-Fi is connected. You will need to ask the network administrators if they are using a proxy for Internet access.

Comment: @RonMaupin do you really think app can have conversation with network administrator regarding access? What kind of stupid answer is that..

Comment: I don't think you understood what I said. If the network uses a proxy for Internet access, you will need to ask the network administrators if you want to know that. The proxy can be a separate box out on the edge of the network. It has nothing to do with Wi-Fi, and you have no way of knowing this without asking the network administrators.